# Keeping even spaces between cell, yet raggedarray for the last one

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

The case below is fine except for the middle cell, I would have wanted it to be centered.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}
    {\textwidth}
    {@{}l@{}C@{}R@{}}
    Foo
    & Bar
    & Qux\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot]

Comment: Change l to X and you should get the desired output.

Comment: To be more precise: \begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {@{}XCL@{}} should work.

Comment: @leandriis, I guess you meant R, not L. Yeah, it worked. I'll post it as the answer unless you do first.

Comment: Yes, sorry, for the typo. `XCR` was what I meant. This is also alread included in [egreg`s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510647/134144).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second column *is* center aligned:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\zerovline}{\kern-0.5\arrayrulewidth\vline\kern-0.5\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\zerovline}l@{\zerovline}C@{\zerovline}R@{\zerovline}}
Foo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{}C@{}R@{}}
Foo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The first version uses `\zerovline` defined just for the example so as to show the margins of the columns.

[image]

This is the output if (in both `tabularx` instances) `l` is replaced by `X`.

[image]

Comment: That's useful but for now not looking for vertical sep.

Comment: @Erwann The vertical rules are used just to show the boundaries of the cells and check the alignment. I typeset the same table twice, one with the rules and one without as in your code.

Comment: I realized that with a time lag then checkmarked.