# Adjust cells width such that rows look balanced

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

This is continued from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510623/keeping-even-spaces-between-cell-yet-raggedarray-for-the-last-one) where I asked how to keep "even spaces between cells". The approach I started from was the one below first rule, that of the answer is just after the first rule. Unfortunately, this does not produce a balanced aspect if the content of the cells are of different sizes (after second rule).  What I would like specifically, here, is the space between `Foooooooooooooooooo` and `Bar` to equal that between `Bar` and `Qux`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\zerovline}{\kern-0.5\arrayrulewidth\vline\kern-0.5\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\zerovline}l@{\zerovline}C@{\zerovline}R@{\zerovline}}
Foo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{}C@{}R@{}}
Foo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}

\hrule

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\zerovline}X@{\zerovline}C@{\zerovline}R@{\zerovline}}
Foo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}C@{}R@{}}
Foo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}

\hrule

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\zerovline}l@{\zerovline}C@{\zerovline}R@{\zerovline}}
Foooooooooooooooooo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}C@{}R@{}}
Foooooooooooooooooo & Bar & Qux
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot]

Comment: Use tabular* in combination with @{\extracolsep{\fill}} instead of tabularx.

Comment: 99 times out of 100 it is better to simply use `tabular` artificially spacing the columns to force the table to be full width always makes it harder to read for no actual benefit.

Comment: This seems to work. `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr}`. Although leaves a gap between `Qux` and edge of body of text.

Comment: `{...cr@{}}` removes the gap near the edge.